# Python - Enforce non-occurence of bool in list

Tags: python-2.7

I want to check in python 2.7 if a dictionary satisfies some restrictions I set. An satisfying example is: `{1:[2], 2: [2,3], 3:False, 4: True}`, however `{1:[1, True]}` is not ok. I want to forbid that keys map to `True` or `False` which are inside a list. Note, that I only want to detect if my restrictions are violated, I don't want to handle the case.

In the beginning I tested if a key maps to a list, and if it does I test if I have for some entry `v`: `v == False or v == True`, and if so I raise an `ValueError`. Then I learned that it does not work, because `1 == True` is true.

Should I instead test `v is False or v is True`? Do you have suggestions on how to enforce the restrictions, or do you think my restrictions are bad practice?

Background: The dictionary maps state/label-tuples to successor states for an NFA, and I map to `True` and `False` to immediately accept/reject the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isinstance`:

```
In [16]: isinstance(True, bool)
Out[16]: True

In [17]: isinstance(1, bool)
Out[17]: False
```

You can use `is` as well:

```
In [18]: any(x is True or x is False for x in [True, 2])
Out[18]: True
```

An example one-line function with `isinstance`:

```
In [21]: is_good = lambda d: not any(any(isinstance(x, bool) for x in l)
   ....: for l in d.values() if isinstance(l, list))

In [22]: d = {1:[2], 2: [2,3], 3:False, 4: True}

In [23]: is_good(d)
Out[23]: True

In [24]: d[1][0] = False

In [25]: is_good(d)
Out[25]: False
```

A more explicit version of the same function:

```
def is_good(d):
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for x in v:
                if isinstance(v, bool):
                    return False
    return True
```

Comment: I like the idea with isinstance, as I do not need to differ between True/False, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To respect duck-typing, if I did not want elements with a length to test true, I would test that, using len(), in addition to == True:

```
def issingle(v):
  try:
    len(v)
    return False
  except:
    return True

x=[2,3]
y=1

issingle(x) ->> False
issingle(y) ->> True
```